# cp using awked lines

Tags: stdin, cp

```
var=$(pwd);diff -x .DS* -r aa bb | cut -f3,4 -d' '| sed 's/\://' | awk -v "var=$var" 'BEGIN{OFS="/"} {split($2,a,"-"); a[1]=toupper(a[1]) if ($1 ~/^bb/) {print var, $1, $2 " " var, "aa"} 
else {print var, $1, $2 " " var, "bb"}}' | cp -r $(cut -f1 -d" ") $(cut -f2 -d" ")
```

This compares two directories and returns source and target addresses for copying purposes. The intended result is that both folders end up with the same files and folders inside them.

The cp-cut part doesn't work. Doing the cp manually produces the right result. The cut operations output seems OK.

Leaving off the cp-cut clause, the script produces lines like this

> /Users/tom/Desktop/aa/AWK/awk-parse-email-add-or.textClipping /Users/tom/Desktop/bb

So this is the raw material - source file and target directory - to copy the awk clipping to the folder bb.

Could some kind person suggest where I am going wrong ?

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using command substitution, `$(cut -f1 -d" ")` and `$(cut -f2 -d" ")`, but these commands are not valid because `cut` requires input.

Try using xargs instead. Change your last pipe to:

```
| xargs -n 2 cp -r
```

Comment: Something happens following your suggestion, but it's chaotic. How can I tweak xargs to do the intended cp using the ordered pairs - source & target - which my carefully constructed pipeline produces ?

Comment: I have got the above script to work by omitting the cp and cut clauses completely. The script outputs to text file which I can process with a bash while script. That works but I suspect there may be a way of doing directly via a pipe.